# JavaFx TableView itemProperty does not notifies ChangeListener

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have problem with my TableView element. I adding listener like that:

```
HardwareIdTableView.getItems().addListener(
        (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends FirmwareData.HardwareIdWrapper> change) -> {
            checker.hardwareIdCompleted.setValue(change.getList().size() > 0);
        });
```

*checker.hardwareIdCompleted* is BooleanProperty.
I checked in debugger and new items was added to the TableView, but *hardwareIdCompleted* still resist 'false'.

**P.S.**
I add items to TableView like this:

```
public void addHardwareKey(HardwareIdKeyT key) {
    ObservableList<FirmwareData.HardwareIdWrapper> idKeys = HardwareIdTableView.getItems();

    if (idKeyEditSelected != null) {
        fwData.removeHardwareIdKey(idKeyEditSelected.getIdPattern());
        idKeys.remove(idKeyEditSelected);
    }

    if (!idKeys.contains(key)) {
        HardwareIdTitledPane.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("pane-error"), false);
        idKeys.add(new FirmwareData.HardwareIdWrapper(key));
        fwData.addHardwareIdKey(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: What  are you trying to do? What does the hardwareIdCompleted indicate? If you want to track emptiness of the tableview you may try booleanProperty.bind(Bindings.isNotEmpty(tableiew.getItems()));

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try.
But I am interested why this solution not working ?!

Comment: On my simple test. It is working as expected. The listener is invoked, and the list size is getting increased by the item addition.

Comment: How you add items to the TableView?

Comment: The same as yours, tableview.getItems().add(new Item(...)); Are you sure that the listener is being invoked? What it shows when you debug the list size?

Comment: In debug mode, size of list increasing. But listener doesn't invoked(no stop on breakpoint inside lamda-listener).

Comment: Are you sure the line idKeys.add(new FirmwareData.HardwareIdWrapper(key)); is invoked? If yes, then you need to provide more complete code to find the problem.

Comment: Yeap, invoked and size of items Observable list is increased.
I now will try your workaround. A little bit later will ask my teammates, to help. Maybe I made some ridiculous mistake, and just cant see it.

Comment: the problem most probably is somewhere in the code you are _not_ showing ;-) Please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the mis-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The fault was straight - my reset function assigned new list to TableView. Since listener was assigned to old item list, it doesn't get notification, when I was expecting.

Comment: Precisely why you should always post a [MCVE] in your question.