# Listeners of ItemProperty() of TableView don't get invalidated (javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to let a program react when a line is added in a TableView, but the ItemProperty doesn't notify the listeners when the list is changed.

I think that might be because I don't 'set' the items (as a new **different** list) but just add to the list, but I'm not sure.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968036/javafx-tableview-itemproperty-does-not-notifies-changelistener) on stackoverflow, but I don't think it's the same problem (or at least the solution didn't work for me).

Is there any convenient way to fix this?

minimal reproducible example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static Random RG = new Random();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        TableView<Integer> integerTableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Integer, Integer> testColumn = new TableColumn<>("test");
        testColumn.setCellValueFactory(i -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(i.getValue().intValue()).asObject());

        integerTableView.getColumns().add(testColumn);

        Button button = new Button("Add random number");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            integerTableView.getItems().add(RG.nextInt());
        });

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(integerTableView, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        integerTableView.itemsProperty().addListener(e -> System.out.println("Added item"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: why? what do you want to do with such a unspecific notification? You can't tell what _exactly_ happened to the list, it's fired on _any_ modification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Problem & Solution

You're adding the `InvalidationListener` to the `items` property, which is an instance of `ObjectProperty`. A listener on that property will not know when something happens to the value it contains (it doesn't even know if/when its value is observable). You need to add the listener to the `ObservableList` itself.

```java
// javafx.beans.Observable
integerTableView
    .getItems()
    .addListener((Observable e) -> System.out.println("Items invalidated!"));
```

---

#### ListChangeListener

Note that an `InvalidationListener` on an `ObservableList` will be fired for any kind of change done to the list, and you won't be aware of what kind of change was done. If you want details about the change, then you should use a `ListChangeListener`.

```java
// javafx.collections.ListChangeListener
integerTableView.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<Integer>) c -> {
  while (c.next()) {
    // process change (see documentation for more info)
  }
});
```

Comment: hmm .. possible (and certainly has a wow-really-had-forgotten-that-observablelist-is-an-observable effect on me :) - but very unsual: why on earth would anybody throw away the details of a Change (which is what the invalidation notification is doing: passing on only the change.getList)? For future readers: don't don't don't .. instead learn how to use a ListChangeListener.

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to do something regardless of the type of change (which, of course, you could also do with a `ListChangeListener`). Anyway, I added some info about `ListChangeListener` to my answer.

Comment: Thats also "the philosophy" of the Model View Controller pattern, I think. When somthing changed, the Observable notifies its listeners and than they get the information needed themselves.

Comment: not convinced by the philosophy argument - but then .. :) BTW: to reliably re-wire the listener (invalidation or listChange doesn't matter) when the value of the itemsProperty is changed, we need an InvalidationListener in the itemsProperty (_not_ a ChangeListener). That's because the changeListener checks equality (which is true for lists of the same size containing the same or equal items) - InvalidationListener checks identity.

Comment: @kleopatra Well that's interesting. It also seems backwards. An `InvalidationListener` should be notified no matter what. A `ChangeListener` should be notified if two references are not the same object (even if they are logically equal).

Comment: And looking at the source code, it looks like you're right. But that seems to disagree with [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html): "_All implementing classes in the JavaFX library check for a change using reference equality (and not object equality, Object#equals(Object)) of the value._". Looks like a bug. Which is the bug, documentation or implementation, not sure (though I lean towards the implementation being wrong).

Comment: equality vs. identity is a long standing discussion - [some notes](https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/wiki/List-Valued-Property-Woes) from years ago.

Comment: the sentence you cited was introduced in fixing  [JDK-8228570](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8228570) - producing a kind-of doc error, IMO: technically, it's correct that all concrete implementations of ObservableValue fire on identity change always. The actual decision of when to notify listeners is delegated to ExpressionHelper, though. Which is implemented to notify changeListeners based on equality.

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
integerTableView.itemsProperty().addListener(e -> System.out.println("Added item"));}
```

by this

```
integerTableView.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener )(e -> {System.out.println("Added item");}));
```

!!!! you need to cast lambda (ListChangeListener ) otherwise you will get "reference to addlistener is ambiguous "  warning , because there are more listeners for that Class